# What are the connection of continuation monads to Traversables/Observables/Futures in Scala?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, monads, continuations

The continuation monad, if written in Scala, is basically

```scala
opaque type Cont[R, +A] = (A => R) => R
```

This type signature, `(A => R) => R`, is suspiciously similar to `foreach` in `Traversable`/`Future` etc:

```scala
def foreach[R](f: A => R) => Unit
```

If written in a lambda form, and assuming `R =:= Unit`, this is `(A => Unit) => Unit`, which is a continuation of return type `Unit`.

I do not fully understand the connection here: can we safely consider `Traversable`/`Observable`s as continuations which admits a callback function `A => Unit`?

Comment: No, they're not similar at all. You are missing that `forEach` is a *method* which takes an instance as its invisible zeroth parameter.

Comment: @Bergi I know that -- the `this` traversable would just be the continuation instance. Given `xs: Traversable[A]`, would `xs.foreach` be a continuation monad?